# I should use for, while or foreach array multidimensional calculation?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, calculator

```
$price = array(
    'value' => 40,
    'mo_desc' => array(
        'monthly' => 1,
        'quartely' => 0.95,
        'semi-anualy' => 0.90,
        'anualy' => 0.85,
        'bi-anualy' => 0.75
    ),
    'plan_desc' => array(
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 1.9,
        'tree' => 3.6,
        'four' => 6.8,
        'five' => 9.6,
        'six' => 12,
        'seven' => 16.8,
        'eight' => 20.8
    )
);
```

I need to get variables combination.

```
$price_monthly_plan_one = $price['value'] * $price['mo_desc']['monthly'] * $price['plan_desc']['one'];
$price_quartely_plan_one = $price['value'] * $price['mo_desc']['quartely'] * $price['plan_desc']['one'];
$price_quartely_plan_two = $price['value'] * $price['mo_desc']['quartely'] * $price['plan_desc']['two'];
```

...
I tried a lot with for, while and foreach. I cant do that. If someone can help!

**I'm trying to do a function where I'll send $price and the function will return the prices like this:**

```
$price = array(
    'plan_1' => array ('price_monthly' => 40,'price_quartely' => xx,'price_semi-anualy' => xx,'price_anualy' => xx,'price_bianualy' => xx),
    'plan_2' => array ('price_monthly' => 40,'price_quartely' => xx,'price_semi-anualy' => xx,'price_anualy' => xx,'price_bianualy' => xx),
    'plan_3' => array ('price_monthly' => 40,'price_quartely' => xx,'price_semi-anualy' => xx,'price_anualy' => xx,'price_bianualy' => xx),
    'plan_4' => array ('price_monthly' => 40,'price_quartely' => xx,'price_semi-anualy' => xx,'price_anualy' => xx,'price_bianualy' => xx),
    'plan_5' => array ('price_monthly' => 40,'price_quartely' => xx,'price_semi-anualy' => xx,'price_anualy' => xx,'price_bianualy' => xx),
    'plan_6' => array ('price_monthly' => 40,'price_quartely' => xx,'price_semi-anualy' => xx,'price_anualy' => xx,'price_bianualy' => xx),
    'plan_7' => array ('price_monthly' => 40,'price_quartely' => xx,'price_semi-anualy' => xx,'price_anualy' => xx,'price_bianualy' => xx),
    'plan_8' => array ('price_monthly' => 40,'price_quartely' => xx,'price_semi-anualy' => xx,'price_anualy' => xx,'price_bianualy' => xx)
);
```

Hard... very hard... trying for more than 8 hours!

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: you mean $price[$counter]['value'] ... ?

Comment: Have edited with more info!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195369/i-should-use-for-while-or-foreach-array-multidimensional-calculation/19195508#19195508

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<?php

$price = array(
    'value' => 40,
    'mo_desc' => array(
        'monthly' => 1,
        'quartely' => 0.95,
        'semi-anualy' => 0.90,
        'anualy' => 0.85,
        'bi-anualy' => 0.75
    ),
    'plan_desc' => array(
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 1.9,
        'tree' => 3.6,
        'four' => 6.8,
        'five' => 9.6,
        'six' => 12,
        'seven' => 16.8,
        'eight' => 20.8
    )
);


    foreach ($price['mo_desc'] as $mo_desc_key=>$mo_desc_val) {
        foreach ($price['plan_desc'] as $plan_desc_key=>$plan_desc_val) {
            $var_name   = 'price_'.$mo_desc_key.'_plan_'.$plan_desc_key;
            $$var_name = $price['value'] * $mo_desc_val * $plan_desc_val;
        }
    }
echo $price_monthly_plan_one."<br>";  // Output 40
echo $price_quartely_plan_one."<br>"; // Output 38
echo $price_quartely_plan_two."<br>"; // Output 72.2
```

Comment: Well, it's working! +1
And now i see, i need to improve my price array with number of the monthly's.
Getting bad price when we use eg: $price_anualy_seven
Need to be $price_anualy_seven * 12.
But now, i believe with your foreachs i can study and maybe I'm able to do this.
Thank you. That help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$price = array(
    'value' => 40,
    'mo_desc' => array(
        'monthly' => 1,
        'quartely' => 0.95,
        'semi-anualy' => 0.90,
        'anualy' => 0.85,
        'bi-anualy' => 0.75
    ),
    'plan_desc' => array(
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 1.9,
        'tree' => 3.6,
        'four' => 6.8,
        'five' => 9.6,
        'six' => 12,
        'seven' => 16.8,
        'eight' => 20.8
    )

);

$value = $price['value'];
$mo_desc = $price['mo_desc'];
$plan_desc = $price['plan_desc'];

foreach($mo_desc as $key=> $month) {

   echo '<h2>'.$key.'</h2>';

   foreach($plan_desc as $key1=> $plan) {
        echo '<br />Price '.$key. ' plan '.$key1.': ';
        $price = $value * $month * $plan;
        echo $price;
        echo ('<br />');
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for you too. It's more then i need. The problem with * 12 for annually i can set at 'mo_desc' instead of 0.85 i I'll use 10.2 (0.85 * 12). Omg, with this i see that I'm so noob. Only 4 or 5 lines and it's ready to use. I tried with 50, 60 lines and can't. Thank you guys. Really loved you!

Comment: Cool enjoy the development :)